# Alternating List

Tags: scheme

I need to make a function that detects whether a list is alternating between atoms and sublists. So for instance it will return true if the list was (a (bc) d (ef)) or false if the list was (a b)

This is what I have so far:

```
(define (altlist? lis)
(cond
((null? lis)#t)
((null? (cdr lis))#t)
((list? (car lis))
 (not(list? (cadr lis)
            (altlist? cdr lis)
           '() )
     (list? (cadr lis)
            (altlist? cdr lis)
           '())
     ))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Functions `list?` and `not` accept a single argument (see http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_sec_11.1), and it's incomprehensible what did you mean by the third `cond` clause.

Meanwhile, the solution is even shorter:

```
(define (altlist? lis)
  (cond
   ((null? lis) #f)
   ((null? (cdr lis)) #f)
   ((not
     (eq? (list? (cadr lis))
          (list? (car lis))))
    #t)
   (#t (altlist? (cdr lis)))))
```

The idea is to check subsequent pairs of the given list one after another. And for each compare whether both are lists, or both are atoms. If the list contains lists and atoms, then there will be a pair (list atom) or (atom list), and vice versa.

#### Edit:

As pointed by @molbdnilo, the original function actually trying to check if the list is not alternating.

#### Edit:

Now I see, that the alternating list isn't just a list, containing both lists and atoms, so look at GoZoner solution. The present implementation just checks an atom and a cons to be present in the given list.

Comment: Unfortunately, `(altlist? '(1 2))` --> `#t`. You're missing a `not`.

Comment: You were right, molbdnilo. I was confused by the Steven's code. Corrected.

Comment: Unfortunately, now `(altlist? '(1 (2 3) (4 5)))` --> `#t`.

Comment: Now I see, that the alternating list isn't just a list, containing both lists and atoms, so look at GoZoner solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
(define (alt-list? l)
  (or (null? l)
      (and (not (null? (cdr  l)))
           (not (list? (car  l)))  ; atom
           (list? (cadr l))        ; list
           (alt-list? (cddr l)))))
```

The exact code will depend on if the following are 'alternating lists':

1. '(a (b c) d)
2. '((a b) c)

My provided code expects (atom list)* => #t

Comment: The (1 (2 3) (4 5)) is the alternating list, but your implementation: `(alt-list? '(1 (2 3) (4 5)))` gives `#f`

Comment: Is '(1 (2 3) (4 5)) an alternating list?  I figured '(1 (2 3) 4 (5 6)) would be? "Alternating between atoms and sublists"

Comment: I didn't understand the concept of alternating list, and now I see, that you solution is right, unlike mine. Thank you.

Comment: is `((1 2) 3 (4 5) 6)` the list that alternates between atoms and sublists?

Answer (score 0):

Here's your code, with some parentheses moved around, some comments and indentation added (to make it readable), and a few corrections:

```
(define (altlist? lis)
  (cond
    ((null? lis) #t)                  ; end-of-list successfully reached
    ((null? (cdr lis)) #t)            ; ditto
    ((list? (car lis))                ; first elt is a list
      (and (not (list? (cadr lis)))   ; fixed: use AND
           (altlist? (cdr lis))))
    (else                             ; fixed: ELSE clause
      (and (list? (cadr lis))         ; fixed: use AND
           (altlist? (cdr lis))))))
```

so you were close. Just be careful in writing down your code.

There is one subtlety here. `(list? '())` returns true. If you prefer to consider the empty list an atom, not a list, then instead of `list?` you can use `pair?`.